# How to access session variables in Twig template?

Tags: theming, sessions

In a custom module I specified in the `hook_preprocess_page` function the following session variable:

```
if (isset($blockNameState) && $blockNameState == 'open') {
   $tempstore->set($blockNameState, 'close');
}
else {
   $tempstore->set($blockNameState, 'open');
}
```

Let's assume the above code ran with `$blockNameState = 'block1_state'` and there is key/value pair 'block1_state/open' in the `$tempstore`.

How do I access the key/value pair in a Twig template?

Can't run the following PHP command in Twig:

```
$blockNameState = $tempstore->get($blockNameState);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can inject new variables into templates by using the appropriate preprocess hook in your theme:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  // code to get value...
  $variables['myvariable'] = $value;
}
```

Then in the corresponding template:

`{{ myvariable }}`

You might have caching issues with this though.