# How to pass variables to overridden Twig template located in module?

Tags: 8, theming, hooks

I'd like to pass a variable to an overridden Twig template that is located in my custom module (not in a theme).

Following [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/264765/85453) and [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/269258/85453), I wrote this code in *mymodule.module*:

```
function mymodule_preprocess_page(array &$variables) {
  $variables['hello'] = 'world';
}

function mymodule_theme_suggestions_node_add_list(array $variables) {
  $suggestions = [];
  $suggestions[] = 'node_add_list__' . 'custom';
  return $suggestions;
}

function mymodule_theme() {
  return [
    'node_add_list__custom' => [
      'base hook' => 'node_add_list',
    ],
  ];
}
```

Then, I have added in *mymodule/templates/node-add-list--custom.html.twig*:

```
myvar: {{ hello }}
```

However nothing appears after "myvar: " when I refresh the page. **I mention that I cleared the cache**.

Is there something specific to manage when we use `hook_preprocess_page()` with `hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK()`/`hook_theme()`?

Comment: You’re adding a variable to the “page” template - that’s not going to be available in other templates, just derivatives of page.html.twig.

Comment: Try to take a look at this page, https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/186010/how-do-i-use-a-preprocess-function-for-a-node-template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `function MYMODULE_preprocess_node_add_list`.

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_node_add_list(array &$variables) {
  $variables['hello'] = 'world';
}
```

This preprocess hook is actually called [`HOOK_preprocess_HOOK`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/8.2.x). See the last `HOOK` in its name? You need to target the `'base hook'` which is `node_add_list`. So preprocess that instead of the page.